# Parsing Custom String in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have string like:

```
"../blabla/here_is_same0000:00/0000:00:1A.0/blabla/blabla/blabla"
```

I want to get 1A.0 part from the string and returning as decimal. These place always comes after the here_is_same0000:00 pattern. Also these places (0000:00:1A.0) not always third place in the given string.

I wrote a code like :

```cpp
static const std::string test_str1{"../blabla/here_is_same0000:00/0000:00:1A.0/blabla/blabla/blabla"};

std::tuple<int, int> values(const std::string& in)
{
  static const std::string constant_pattern{"here_is_same0000:00"};
  std::size_t found_idx = in.find(constant_pattern);
  if(found_idx == std::string::npos)
  {
    return std::make_tuple(0,0);
  }

  std::string remaining = in.substr(found_idx + constant_pattern.length() + 1, in.length());
  
  found_idx = remaining.find("/");
  if(found_idx == std::string::npos)
  {
    return std::make_tuple(0,0);
  }

  remaining = remaining.substr(0, found_idx);
  found_idx = remaining.find_last_of(":");
  remaining = remaining.substr(found_idx + 1, remaining.length());

  std::stringstream ss(remaining);
  std::string items;
  std::vector<std::string> elements;
  while(std::getline(ss, items, '.'))
  {
    elements.push_back(std::move(items));
  }

  int x;
  std::stringstream ss_convert_x;
  ss_convert_x << std::hex << elements[0];
  ss_convert_x >> x;
  
  int y;
  std::stringstream ss_convert_y;
  ss_convert_y << std::hex << elements[1];
  ss_convert_y >> y;

  std::cout << x <<" "<< y;
  
  return std::make_tuple(x,y);
}
```

But it looks like bad to me, is there any better way ?

Comment: why does it look bad to you? What do you mean with "better" ?

Comment: What about using a regular expression for the parsing?

Comment: does it work? Then leave it be. Unless you have a test that fails or some objective criterion that the code fails to meet, you should not touch it. "looks bad" is not an objective criterion. You can change the code and there is no clear way to tell if a change made an improvement or not

Comment: I would say that the better way (in terms of being able to understand and modify the code) would be to use a regular expression.

Comment: To parse a custom string in C++, you will need to use the std::string library. This library provides many useful methods for manipulating strings, such as the substr() method which you can use to extract substrings from a string. Additionally, you can use the std::stringstream class to parse the string using the >> operator. This class provides various methods to convert string objects into different types like int, float, double, etc. Finally, you can use the find() method to locate a specific character or substring in a string.

Comment: I want to write this code more readable @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: Could you give an example regex expression for the string which i mentioned in the question @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by others and even suggested by your term "pattern", a "regex" is the way to go.

In this case you can simply use `std::regex_search`. Please read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search).

The advantage is that, if the search function returns success, then you can be sure that the numbers are in the correct format. So the `std::stoi` function will always work.

The regex can be developed by using an online regex tester page like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rJvsNL/1).

The implementation will then be very simple. Please see the below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <tuple>

const std::string test{"../blabla/here_is_same0000:00/0000:00:1A.0/blabla/blabla/blabla"};

const std::regex re{R"(.*?here_is_same0000:00\/0000:00:([0-9a-fA-F]+)\.(\d).*)"};

std::tuple<int, int> values(const std::string& in) {
    
    std::tuple<int, int> result{};
    if (std::smatch sm{};std::regex_search(test, sm, re))
        result = {std::stoi(sm[1],nullptr,16),std::stoi(sm[2])};
    return result;
}

int main() {
    const auto& [i1,i2] = values(test);
    std::cout << i1 << ' ' << i2 << '\n';
}
```